# PostgreSQL fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, unix, ansible

I know there are thousands of questsions like this one here on SO but i've seen them all and i'm still not able to deal with my problem.

I'm doing everything using ansible so it's quite automated but, anyway, here are my files:

#### pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             10.11.12.0/24           md5
```

#### database.yml

```
production:
  database: my_db
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: deploy
  encoding: unicode
  min_messages: WARNING
  template: template0
```

And i have a `deploy` user (and postgres user without a password set) in my system created. And now, while i'm totally able to sign in to postgres from bash using `psql -d my_db` (on server), i'm not able to connect to the db with my rails app. Running rake db:migrateMigration gives me

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I'm quite terrible at beeing a devop and i'm fighting with that issue from the day before yesterday's morning and it's still here so if there is anyone who can help me with that, i would be be more than grateful.

Comment: psql is using a local socket connection, rails is using localhost over TCP/IP. Local is trusted, localhost requires an password (using md5). You could setup a pgpass file for your rails user: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: Yes that was it! I didn't knew that rails connects to postgres in a different way than user. Thank you! Please add it as an answer so i can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

psql is using a local socket connection, rails is using localhost over TCP/IP. Local is trusted, localhost requires a password (using md5). You could setup a pgpass file for your rails user: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: how come in my case, psql is complaining about an empty password when connecting via localhost:5432, but when using pgAdmin III, connecting via localhost:5432 works?

Answer (score 0):

In C you can do it like this, I don't even know what Rails is

```
conninfo = "hostaddr = 127.0.0.1 dbname = bitcoin user = alan password = mypass";
conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
```

I had exactly the same error message.