# postgresql database migration error: PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to run `rake db:migrate` in my rails app, but getting the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

My `database.yml` is as follow:

```
<%
  branch = `git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null`.chomp.sub('refs/heads/', '')
  branch = 'master' if branch.empty?
  suffix = branch == 'master' || branch.starts_with?('hotfix') ? '' : "_" + `git config --local --get offgrid.databases.#{branch.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/,'')}`.strip
  suffix = ENV['DB_SUFFIX'] if ENV['DB_SUFFIX']
  puts "Database is 'offgrid_dev#{suffix}'" if Rails.env.development?
%>

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: offgrid_dev<%= suffix %>
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  password: 1

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: offgrid_test<%= suffix %><%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  password: 1
```

the more confusing thing here is that when I try migrating my test database as follow:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

my test database gets migrated successfully, without giving the password error.

this is very confusing, as I have more-or-less the same configuration for both test and development environment.

My first question is why is this so?

More importantly though, How do I get to overcome this?

I have tried to change password to be nothing, by using the `psql` console to set the password as: `\password <username>`, and hitting return with no input for new password, and confirmation, and then running the migration, with no success. I have also tried to run the migration while specifying the environment as: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` with no success as well

What am I doing awfull, and how can I get this up?

Big thanks for all help.

PS: my OS is ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whao... after searching more on `stackoverflow`, I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27419961/4330954), which points to [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

On following that, and configuring my `.pgpass` file with default `username` and `password` as said in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html), all worked fine!!!!

Although, I still do not understand why it was previously working for my test env database, but not the development env database.